# Bundling a PyQt5 application using py2app: keep getting "Abort trap: 6" error

Tags: python, pyqt, py2app, pyqt5

I am trying to create an OS X application from this code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.lastWindowClosed.connect(app.quit)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I'm in OS X 10.10 using py2app (0.9.1) and PyQt5 (5.4.0) in Python 2.7.9. The app seems to be built just fine. Upon launching the app, it immediately crashes with "Abort trap: 6".

I've tried using the default setup.py created by py2applet as well as generating the app directly from py2applet. The python file itself runs without crashing.

Any ideas/help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You import `QApplication` and then you try to instantiate it using the package name: `QtWidgets.QApplication` Apart from that, I used the following setup.py and it worked:

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(
app=["MyApplication.py"],
setup_requires=["py2app"],
)
```

Running the command `python3 setup.py py2app -A --packages=PyQt5` produced a working app. When you get an error, check Console for any output. This can help when debugging.

As a side note, when I pack PyQt app, I usually also copy over any Qt pluggins and run the `macdeployqt` tool to fix linking.:

```
cp -R /Developer/Qt/5.3/clang_64/plugins/ dist/MyApplication.app/Contents/PlugIns
macdeployqt dist/MyApplication.app
```

Comment: Thanks for the QApplication fix. I messed that up when copying the code over. That's not what's causing this to fail, as you might guess.

Comment: using the -A flag works on my local machine, but will cause the app to fail on any machine without all the required libs. macdeployqt may fix any Qt plugins' linking issues, but not all the libraries I'd need to copy over for my actual application. Can you think of a way to make this work without -A?

Comment: Try copying the Qt plugins and running macdeployqt. That worked for me.

Comment: Also, add `import sip` and `import PyQt5` into your python code. py2app will use it to add the dependencies.

Comment: I'm having the same problem as described here. However, when I try to run macdeployqt I get error about not finding python 2.7 files: ERROR: no file at "/usr/local/opt/python/lib/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python I suspect that qt for some reason looks 2.7. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: I would start by checking the PATH and make sure that the right version of Python is found first.

Answer (score 1):

After struggling with this problem for a while and not being able to find a solution, I switched to [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) which worked for me with PyQt 5.6.1 out of the box. I detailed some of my findings and why I ended up picking PyInstaller over other available freezers in a [blog post](https://fman.io/blog/codesigning-and-automatic-updates-for-pyqt-apps/).